# why is not enabled

Tags: jquery, pagination, resize

I'm working on pagination, and part of pagination involves resizing columns using jquery colResizable. I have two buttons, one for enable colResizable and one for colResizable disable.

The button #resize id works great when disabled, but if I want to enable, the button for resizeenb is not working after disabled. I have tried if and else statements but it still didn't work. Does anyone know why is not working and how to solve it?

```
$('#resize').click(function () {
    if ($('#sample2').is(':disabled') == false) {
        $('#sample2').colResizable({
            disable: true
        });
    }
});
$('#resizebs').click(function () {
    if ($('#sample2').is(':disabled') == true) {
        $('#sample2').colResizable({
            disable: false
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: do you any JsFiddle for that ?

Answer (score 0):

after disabling colResizable, if you want to enable it, you have to call it normally again.

```
 $('#sample2').colResizable({ livedrag:true }); //enables colresizable
 $('#sample2').colResizable({ disable:true }); //disables colresizable 
 $('#sample2').colResizable({ livedrag:true }); //enables colresizable again
```